# dotData in owl carousel 2 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

So I am trying to get the dot data working in the Owl Carousel 2 as outlined in the [docs](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-options.html). However no matter what I do the dot data I add never appears. I put together a fiddle example to show this.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    nav: false, // Show next and prev buttons
    smartSpeed: 450,
    loop: false,
    dotData: true
});

<div class="owl-carousel">
<div data-dot="1"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x200/008CBA/FFFFFF/&text=1" alt=""></div>
<div data-dot="2"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x200/008CBA/FFFFFF/&text=2" alt=""></div>
<div data-dot="3"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x200/008CBA/FFFFFF/&text=3" alt=""></div>
<div data-dot="4"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x200/008CBA/FFFFFF/&text=4" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e8v31thz/1/

The JS file was just downloaded from the site. I found this beta build of the js [online](http://demo.lanrenzhijia.com/2014/owl0509/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js?v=beta.1.8) and it does work.

What am I missing here? Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 4):

In latest version of owl carousel use `dotsData: true` instead of `dotdata: true` as said in docs

Comment: It still shows 'dotData' in the documentation. https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the latest version from [OwlCarousel](http://smashingboxes.github.io/OwlCarousel2/index.html) ?

Also, you are not including the OwlCarousel CSS theme, it doesn't come in the package, you can use this one [OWL Default Theme FIle](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css).

Another option could be that you have too few slides but that's just a theory.

Comment: Yes this is the latest version. I downloaded it today.

Adding that theme file had no effect.

How would too few slides effect it?

Here is the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e8v31thz/2/

Comment: I tried it without `dotData` and it works fine. I added the `dotData: true` and it's not generating the dots.

Afterwards I reviewed the `owl.carousel.js` file and found this 

`/*** Draws the user interface. * @todo The option 'dotData' wont work. * @protected */`

The plugin is still in beta version so I guess the version you saw is using something different.

Comment: Where did you find this? I don't see that in the repo or in the downloaded code.

Comment: So I found a ticket with this issue documented. I didn't see it before. https://github.com/smashingboxes/OwlCarousel2/issues/1034. It looks like it worked in beta 1.8 but it's broken in beta 3.0  http://demo.lanrenzhijia.com/2014/owl0509/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js?v=beta.1.8

Comment: I saw it inside the main JS file. I was checking the part where it generates the dots nav.